# ngCordova Geolocation plugin with Ionic framework 1 not working on Android

Tags: android, ionic-framework, geolocation, ngcordova

I'm trying to get current address on Google map with Cordova and Ionic framework, very simple project.

Here is the code I have done.

1. index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">

    <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
    <script>
      if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
          .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
          .catch(err => console.log('Error', err));
      }
    </script>-->

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-pane ng-controller="AppCtrl">
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Location</h1>
        <button class="button button-clear button-royal pull-right" ng-click="uploadLocation()">
          <i class="icon ion-ios-upload">Upload</i>
        </button>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
        <div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
    <script src="https://maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

2. app.js

```js
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaGeolocation, $ionicLoading, $http, $ionicPopup, $ionicPlatform) {
  
    $ionicLoading.show({
        template: '<ion-spinner icon="bubbles"></ion-spinner><br/>Acquiring location!'
    });
      
    var posOptions = {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 20000,
        maximumAge: 0
    };

    $scope.currentLocation = null;

    $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(posOptions).then(function (position) {
        var lat  = position.coords.latitude;
        var long = position.coords.longitude;
          
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
          
        var mapOptions = {
            center: myLatlng,
            zoom: 16,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };          
          
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
        geocoder.geocode({ 'location': myLatlng }, function(results, status) {
          if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: myLatlng,
              map: map,
              title: 'I an here!'
            });

            $scope.currentLocation = results[0].formatted_address;
            console.log($scope.currentLocation);
          }
        })          
          
        $scope.map = map;   
        $ionicLoading.hide();           
          
    }, function(err) {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        console.log(err);
    });
    $scope.uploadLocation = function() {
                       console.log(5555555555)
      var link = 'http://dashboard.tiniestory.com/api/set';
      $http.post(link, {location: $scope.currentLocation})
        .then(function(res) {
            $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: 'Alert',
                template: 'Your location "' + $scope.currentLocation + '" has been sent to the server.'
            });
        });
    }
})

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
```

3. style.css

```css
#map {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

It works fine on both Browser and iOS device.
But not working on Android, how can I fix this?

Comment: console error , warning?

Comment: Are you getting the current position ? Or only map is not loading ? Can you provide some more information ? As @Antonis said, is there any error or warning in console ?

Comment: Google map is not loading, and position is null, but it works correctly on browser and iPhone device.